# Как установить текущий colorAccent внутри стиля?

Tags: android, xml, android-style

У меня есть несколько стилей приложения с разными colorAccent. Вот пример такого стиля:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/yellow_amber</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryRipple</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Дальше я хочу аналогично установить стиль для диалога, чтобы его colorAccent совпадал с общем стилем.

```
<style name="FullScreenDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorSplashScreenBG</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Я пытаюсь установить необходимый цвет: `<item name="actionMenuTextColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>`
Но, во время работы, приложение крашится. Я так понимаю, он так не понимает текущий colorAccent. Как тогда быть?

**Логи:**

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84: Binary XML file line #84: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x101009b a=1}
```

Comment: Очень всем поможет, если вы логи падения приведёте в вопросе. Очень вероятно, что это самое важное и позволит вам помочь

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил логи. Они говорят, что недоступен ресурс. Но ведь я об этом и веду речь, что вообще внутри style можно обращаться к ?colorAccent. Ибо потом я обращаюсь к нему уже в xml.

Comment: Попробуйте в стиле явно задать colorAccent.  `<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorAccent</item>`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогло. Крашится перестало. Но цвет не распознает.